# What is the benefit of upgrading the Hangfire database schema?

Tags: c#, .net-6.0, hangfire, hangfire-sql

I am in the process of upgrading the framework from an older .net framework to .net 6. In this process I also upgraded some of the 3rd party libraries including Hangfire. Looking at the [documentation](https://docs.hangfire.io/en/latest/upgrade-guides/upgrading-to-hangfire-1.8.html) it says that the current 1.8 version of Hangfire will work with the existing schema, my question: what is the benefit to run the [upgrade script](https://github.com/HangfireIO/Hangfire/blob/858f19dfa5fd5fb5b95fe20f9c3f841a7ba658b2/src/Hangfire.SqlServer/DefaultInstall.sql)? I have concerns with making changes to a critical application's (for our organization) SQL unnecessarily or without good reason.